# Dialup on 2009 iMac

Tags: imac, internet, ethernet, modem

I'm going to see a family friend who's been having trouble with her decade old Windows machine. I have an old iMac laying around and I thought I would set her up with it. The only thing is, she lives in such a rural place that the only Internet connection available is dial-up.

How can I connect this iMac to the Internet using dial-up? I know there's an option in `System Preferences -> Network` for the internal modem but do I need an RJ-11 to USB converter or can I just plug the RJ-11 into the RJ-45 port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, you cannot plug the RJ-11 into the Ethernet port and have it work for a Dial-Up Connection.

There were five 2009 iMac models...

- iMac (20-inch, Early 2009)
- iMac (24-inch, Early 2009)
- iMac (20-inch, Mid 2009)
- iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2009)
- iMac (27-inch, Late 2009)

None of which had a built-in modem although the first two were offered with an optional Apple USB Modem (MA034Z/A).

If you do not have the Apple USB Modem (MA034Z/A) or a third-party USB Modem that will work on a Mac with the version of OS X and the Dial-Up Service Provider then your iMac will be of little use in this situation.

Comment: I do have an Apple USB Modem which is apparently not compatible with 64bit OSes or > Mac OS X v10.6.8